# flask API calls scheduling with cron jobs

Tags: python, api, flask, cron, apscheduler

I have a function which calls several API's and updates the database upon being called. I want to schedule the function to run daily at specific time.

Already tried flask_apscheduler and APScheduler which gives this error:

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed an active HTTP request. Consult the documentation on testing for information about how to avoid this problem.

Any leads on this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should:

- Post the code where you define your flask application.
- Specify how you try to access the app.
- How you're calling the APIs.
- Whether those APIs are 3rd party or part of your blueprint.

However, this is probably a context issue. I have come across a similar one with SQLAlchemy before.
You will need to somehow get access to your app, either by using app_context or by importing `current_app` from Flask and accessing the config.

1. Assuming you imported the app where your function is used, try this:

   ```
   with app.app_context():
       # call your function here
   ```

   Refer to this document for more information: [Flask Documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/appcontext/)
2. Another approach you can try, is passing your app configurations through a config class object.
   You can define the jobs you want to schedule and pass a reference to your function inside.
   Check this example from [flask-apscheduler](https://github.com/viniciuschiele/flask-apscheduler/blob/master/examples/jobs.py) repository on GitHub.